# Random choices of two values

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

In my algorithm I have two values that I need to choose at random but each one has to be chosen a predetermined number of times.

So far my solution is to put the choices into a vector the correct number of times and then shuffle it. In C++:

```
// Example choices (can be any positive int)
int choice1 = 3; 
int choice2 = 4;

int number_of_choice1s = 5;
int number_of_choice2s = 1;

std::vector<int> choices;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_choice1s; ++i) choices.push_back(choice1);
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_choice2s; ++i) choices.push_back(choice2);
std::random_shuffle(choices.begin(), choices.end());
```

Then I keep an iterator to `choices` and whenever I need a new one I increase the iterator and grab that value.

This works but it seems like there might be a more efficient way. Since I always know how many of each value I'll use I'm wondering if there is a more algorithmic way to go about doing this, rather than just storing the values.

Comment: I'd stick with the working solution unless there is a good reason why not to. Is it profiled as a bottleneck or something like that?

Comment: There is a way but it would be less clear and concise. I would stick with this technique.

Comment: I actually really like this solution as it is. All the other solutions that come to mind (after thinking for about 5 seconds) involve random number generators. But since you have a pre-determined number of each choice, these solutions would be ineffecient as they would ultimately have to start ignoring values after their choice had already occurred the max number of times. (admittedly the shuffle method is potentially a CPU drain, but you can at least make it a predictable running time, which you cant do with the solutions I was thinking of above)

Comment: Shuffle method can be done with a O(n) complexity which is the minimum you can achieve since you have to generate n elements anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are unnecessarily using so much memory. You have two variables:

```
int number_of_choice1s = 5;
int number_of_choice2s = 1;
```

Now simply randomize:

```
int result = rand() % (number_of_choice1s + number_of_choice2s);
if(result < number_of_choice1s) {
  --number_of_choice1s;
  return choice1;
} else {
  --number_of_choice2s;
  return choice2;
}
```

This scales very well two millions of random invocations.

Comment: Once either counter reaches 0 you can short circuit the rest of the process

Comment: How's there bias? This just looks like a customized version of Knuth's select m from n algorithm - +1 from me

Comment: But note that if your standard library happens to have a bad `rand` implementation (e.g., linear congruential with smallish modulus), using `%` like this can introduce bias. Also, `RAND_MAX` may be as small as 32767 (the `rand` in Microsoft's standard library has this property) and you'll lose totally if you have a large number of choices to make.

Comment: (For the avoidance of doubt, I do think this is a good approach.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: I haven't coded in C++ in ages, and I don't know what is the *safe* way of randomizing a value between 0 (inclusive) and N (exclusive) in this language. I just wanted to give an idea, feel free to fix the `rand()` invocation.

Comment: You can't generate an unbiased selection using `%` or `/` unless the number of choices divides evenly into `RAND_MAX+1`. There are lots of posts here on StackOverflow on generating a random choice without bias. I'm not sure how much it matters here though, since the number of choices is constantly changing.

Comment: A biased random distribution will keep some kind of order over the resulting set ( the choice that was picked the most have lesser and lesser chance to be picked next ), which give a biased result.

Comment: Nice! It was the memory requirement that made me think there was a better way.

Comment: An improvement that (I think) would get rid of the bias is to use boost.random to create a random real in [0, 1) and then use this to create the `result`. Assuming I created a function `uni_dev` which returns the random real, I would change your expression for `result` to `int result = uni_dev() * (number_of_choice1s + number_of_choice2s)`

Answer (score 1):

You could write this a bit more simply:

```
std::vector<int> choices(number_of_choice1s, choice1);
choices.resize(number_of_choice1s + number_of_choice2s, choice2);
std::random_shuffle(choices.begin(), choices.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

A biased random distribution will keep some kind of order over the resulting set ( the choice that was picked the most have lesser and lesser chance to be picked next ), which give a biased result (specially if the number of time you have to pick the first value is large compared to the second value, you'll endup with something like this {1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2}.

Here's the code, which looks a lot like the one written by @Tomasz Nurkiewicz but using a simple even/odd which should give about 50/50 chance to pick either values.

```
int result = rand();

if ( result & 1  &&  number_of_choice1s > 0)
{
number_of_choice1s--;
return choice1;
}else if (number_of_choice2s>0)
{
number_of_choice2s--;
return choice2;
}
else
{
return -1;
}
```